# R blogdown::build_site does not generate any files in the public folder

Tags: r, blogdown

I have tried using blogdown to create a personal website with the gcushen theme. Now, blogdown::serve_site() gives me a preview of my website, which looks perfectly fine. However, I am not able to publish the website online as my public folder is empty.

Here is the information about my session:

```
> xfun::session_info('blogdown')
    R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
    Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
    Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6, RStudio 1.2.5042
    Locale: en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / C / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8
    Package version:
      base64enc_0.1.3  blogdown_1.13    bookdown_0.29    bslib_0.3.1      digest_0.6.29    evaluate_0.16   
      fastmap_1.1.0    fs_1.5.2         glue_1.6.2       graphics_3.6.3   grDevices_3.6.3  highr_0.9       
      htmltools_0.5.3  httpuv_1.6.6     jquerylib_0.1.4  jsonlite_1.8.0   knitr_1.40       later_1.3.0     
      magrittr_2.0.3   methods_3.6.3    mime_0.12        promises_1.2.0.1 R6_2.5.1         rappdirs_0.3.3  
      Rcpp_1.0.9       rlang_1.0.6      rmarkdown_2.16   sass_0.4.2       servr_0.24       stats_3.6.3     
      stringi_1.7.8    stringr_1.4.1    tinytex_0.41     tools_3.6.3      utils_3.6.3      xfun_0.33       
      yaml_2.3.5      
    
    Hugo version: 0.104.0
```

Thanks to this post (https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/495), I am aware that I need to use blogdown::build_site() to generate a public folder, but that does not work. I got a very long error message, I have pasted parts of it below.

```
> blogdown::build_site(local = TRUE, run_hugo = TRUE)
Start building sites … 
hugo v0.104.0-c744dbd6edeeb27288c9dd67e0eb92951f911397+extended darwin/amd64 BuildDate=2022-09-23T14:32:56Z VendorInfo=gohugoio
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /Users/minyuchang/Library/Application Support/Hugo/0.104.0/hugo
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /Users/minyuchang/Library/Application Support/Hugo/0.104.0/hugo
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

SIGABRT: abort
PC=0xbf4d9ee m=0 sigcode=0
goroutine 0 [idle]:
syscall.syscall6(0xc000bbcb80?, 0x3d?, 0x8d09108?, 0xc000bbcb80?, 0x3d?, 0xc001085390?, 0x40533d0?)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sys_darwin.go:44 +0x99 fp=0xc001085318 sp=0xc001085258 pc=0x4068a39
syscall.utimensat(0xc001085468?, {0xc000bbcb80?, 0xc001085468?}, 0xc001085458, 0x3d?)
    /usr/local/go/src/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:353 +0x9c fp=0xc001085390 sp=0xc001085318 pc=0x407e43c
syscall.UtimesNano({0xc000bbcb80, 0x3d}, {0xc001085458, 0x3e?, 0x3d?})
    /usr/local/go/src/syscall/syscall_bsd.go:496 +0x79 fp=0xc001085428 sp=0xc001085390 pc=0x407b3d9
os.Chtimes({0xc000bbcb80?, 0x3d}, {0xc000bbcb80?, 0xc0008b2480?, 0x74474e0?}, {0x33?, 0xc0007c2c90?, 0x74474e0?})
    /usr/local/go/src/os/file_posix.go:184 +0x1c5 fp=0xc0010854c8 sp=0xc001085428 pc=0x40b1a25
github.com/spf13/afero.OsFs.Chtimes(...)
    /root/project/gomodcache/github.com/spf13/afero@v1.9.2/os.go:99
github.com/spf13/afero.(*OsFs).Chtimes(0x0?, {0xc000bbcb80?, 0xa?}, {0x0?, 0x0?, 0x74474e0?}, {0xc001085578?, 0x455bf25?, 0x74474e0?})
    <autogenerated>:1 +0x65 fp=0xc001085518 sp=0xc0010854c8 pc=0x448e065
github.com/spf13/afero.(*BasePathFs).Chtimes(0xc0000e4ea0, {0xc0007c2c90?, 0xc000368d20?}, {0xc0007c2ce0?, 0x45763ea?, 0x74474e0?}, {0xc001085608?, 0x457644a?, 0x74474e0?})
    /root/project/gomodcache/github.com/spf13/afero@v1.9.2/basepath.go:88 +0x16a fp=0xc0010855c0 sp=0xc001085518 pc=0x448326a
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugofs.(*hasBytesFs).Chtimes(0x0?, {0xc0007c2c90?, 0x74474e0?}, {0x0?, 0xedac1a631?, 0x74474e0?}, {0x63e7ea0?, 0x63e7ea0?, 0x74474e0?})
    <autogenerated>:1 +0x4b fp=0xc001085618 sp=0xc0010855c0 pc=0x45786eb
github.com/spf13/fsync.(*Syncer).syncstats(0xc001085d90, {0xc0007c2c90, 0xa}, {0xc0007c2ce0, 0xa})
    /root/project/gomodcache/github.com/spf13/fsync@v0.9.0/fsync.go:238 +0x31a fp=0xc0010856d0 sp=0xc001085618 pc=0x571349a
github.com/spf13/fsync.(*Syncer).sync.func1()
    /root/project/gomodcache/github.com/spf13/fsync@v0.9.0/fsync.go:135 +0x36 fp=0xc001085708 sp=0xc0010856d0 pc=0x5713156
github.com/spf13/fsync.(*Syncer).sync(0xc001085d90, {0xc0007c2c90, 0xa}, {0xc0007c2ce0, 0xa})
    /root/project/gomodcache/github.com/spf13/fsync@v0.9.0/fsync.go:171 +0x708 fp=0xc0010859c8 sp=0xc001085708 pc=0x5712b68
github.com/spf13/fsync.(*Syncer).sync(0xc001085d90, {0x63e3ae8, 0x1}, {0x63e3ae8, 0x1})
    /root/project/gomodcache/github.com/spf13/fsync@v0.9.0/fsync.go:197 +0xaec fp=0xc001085c88 sp=0xc0010859c8 pc=0x5712f4c
github.com/spf13/fsync.(*Syncer).syncRecover(0xc000e3ed90?, {0x63e3ae8?, 0x1?}, {0x63e3ae8?, 0x1?})
    /root/project/gomodcache/github.com/spf13/fsync@v0.9.0/fsync.go:128 +0x6c fp=0xc001085cf0 sp=0xc001085c88 pc=0x571230c
github.com/spf13/fsync.(*Syncer).Sync(0xc000e3ed90, {0x63e3ae8, 0x1}, {0x63e3ae8, 0x1})
    /root/project/gomodcache/github.com/spf13/fsync@v0.9.0/fsync.go:103 +0xaa fp=0xc001085d28 sp=0xc001085cf0 pc=0x571222a
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands.(*commandeer).copyStaticTo(0xc0001783c0, 0xc0008e9ea0)
    /root/project/hugo/commands/hugo.go:675 +0x357 fp=0xc001085de0 sp=0xc001085d28 pc=0x5724ad7
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands.(*commandeer).copyStaticTo-fm(0xc000e3ee30?)
    <autogenerated>:1 +0x2c fp=0xc001085e00 sp=0xc001085de0 pc=0x573d48c
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands.(*commandeer).doWithPublishDirs(0xc0001783c0, 0xc001085f08)
    /root/project/hugo/commands/hugo.go:599 +0x163 fp=0xc001085ed0 sp=0xc001085e00 pc=0x57244a3
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands.(*commandeer).copyStatic(0x8?)
    /root/project/hugo/commands/hugo.go:581 +0x39 fp=0xc001085f28 sp=0xc001085ed0 pc=0x57242b9
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands.(*commandeer).fullBuild.func2()
    /root/project/hugo/commands/hugo.go:304 +0x2a fp=0xc001085f78 sp=0xc001085f28 pc=0x572292a
golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(*Group).Go.func1()
    /root/project/gomodcache/golang.org/x/sync@v0.0.0-20210220032951-036812b2e83c/errgroup/errgroup.go:57 +0x67 fp=0xc001085fe0 sp=0xc001085f78 pc=0x4dc6ea7
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594 +0x1 fp=0xc001085fe8 sp=0xc001085fe0 pc=0x406c501
created by golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(*Group).Go
    /root/project/gomodcache/golang.org/x/sync@v0.0.0-20210220032951-036812b2e83c/errgroup/errgroup.go:54 +0x8d
......
```

As a result, my public folder only has a "uploads" subfolder, and nothing is in it.
Could anyone helps me figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the error message, but it seems your macOS version is too low. I'm not sure if Hugo supports that version. If possible, you may upgrade your macOS. Your R and RStudio versions are also very low, but they may be fine. With a quick search, I found this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/87097 which suggests running `xcode-select --install` in the Terminal. I don't know if that would work. I'm on macOS Monterey 12.6 and can't reproduce this problem. BTW, if you publish with Netlify or Vercel, you don't need to build the site locally.

Comment: @Yihui Xie
Thanks for your reply! xcode-select --install does not work for me. I will try publishing with Netlify or Vercel.